# Changing NumberPicker divider color not working with Android Api 29+

Tags: android, divider, numberpicker

I am using below code to change `NumberPicker` divider color,
this code not working with Android Api 29+ because `UnsupportedAppUsage mSelectionDivider`.

```
private static void setDividerColor(NumberPicker picker, int color) {
    java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
      if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
        pf.setAccessible(true);
        try {
          ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
          pf.set(picker, colorDrawable);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | Resources.NotFoundException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create your own widget, rather than trying to use reflection to modify a framework widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`number-picker`](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker) library like this:

```
implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.11'
```

and in xml:

```
<com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/color_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:np_dividerColor="#000000"/>
```

and in java set color:

```
numberPicker.setDividerColor(Color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set This style as android:theme` for number picker :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NumberPickerTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/yourDividerColor</item>
    </style>
```

and

```
<NumberPicker
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NumberPickerTheme"
       />
```